# I have date field was working fine in IE8 but IE11 it’s not working properly

Tags: html, css

If I add top and bottom to align it correctly date is disappearing. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

this is my jsp code:

```
<div class="right-w">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${fsfview.localeUtil.syslocale == 'fr_ca'}">
            <c:set var="weekEnding" value="weekEnding-CA" />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${fsfview.localeUtil.syslocale == 'en_gb'}">
            <c:set var="weekEnding" value="weekEnding-UK" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="weekEnding" value="weekEnding" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <c:out value="${fsfview.localeMap['Week Ending']}"/>: <input type="text" 
    id="${weekEnding}"  class="wkEndingField"value="${fsfview.weekEndingLocale}" 
    onchange="validateWklyViewWkEndDate('<c:out 
    value="${fsfview.localeUtil.syslocale}" />');" 
    onkeypress="checkForEnterKey(event, '<c:out 
    value="${fsfview.localeUtil.syslocale}" />');" style="padding-top: 2px; padding- 
    bottom: 18px;"/>

 </div>
```

and my css code:

/* PAGE HEADER STUFF */
    .page-header .left-w, .page-header .right-w { width: 48%; padding: 2px;  border: 0px 
    dotted #555555; }
    .page-header .left-w { float: left; text-align:left; font-size: 18px; }
   .page-header .right-w { float: right; text-align:right; padding-right: 10px; padding- 
   top: `enter code here`5px; }
   .page-header .right-w input { height: 15px; padding: 2px 4px 4px 18px; width: 105px; 
   border: 1px solid #555555; }